# IabHelper returns an empty inventory

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Good morning, I am using the util class from the example "Trivial Drive" to program an 
in-app purchase for my app. 
So i'm using an iabHelper to comunicate with google play. 
When i query the inventory of the available items, the result is success 
but the returned inventory is empty although i have published an item to 
sell in my developer console. 
 Has anyone have the same problem?
Here is the code and the log.

BILLING MANAGER

```
public BillingManager(Context context, IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener listener){

    Log.d(TAG, "Costruzione...");

    this.context = context;



    iabHelper = new IabHelper(context, base64Key);
    iabHelper.enableDebugLogging(enableLogging);
    iabHelper.startSetup(listener);
}

public void setupReceiver(Activity activity){

    receiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(BillingManager.getBilligBroadcastListener());
    IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
    activity.registerReceiver(receiver, broadcastFilter);
}

/**Distrugge questo BillingManager */
public void destroy(Activity activity){

    Log.d(TAG, "Distruzzione del Billing Manager...");

    Log.d(TAG, "Chiudo il broadcast receiver");
    activity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);

    if(iabHelper != null){
        iabHelper.dispose();
    }

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Invoco Finalize...");
        finalize();
    }
    catch(java.lang.Throwable e){

    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(!started) {

        started = true;

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //          CODICE PER GLI ACQUISTI IN APP
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        billingManager = new BillingManager(getApplicationContext(), this);

    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}

public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result){

    if(billingManager == null){

        Log.e(TAG, "billingManager nullo nella chiamata di onIabSetupFinished");
        return;
    }

    if(billingManager.getIabHelper() == null){

        Log.e(TAG, "IabHelper nullo nella chiamata di onIabSetupFinished");
        return;
    }

    if(result.isSuccess()){

        //Instanzio il broadcast receiver
        billingManager.setupReceiver(this);

        billingManager.setSetupDone(true);

        Log.d(TAG, "Setup dell'IabHelper e del BroadcastReceiver completato con successo.");
        Log.d(TAG, "Richiedo la lista dei prodotti disponibili");

        billingManager.getIabHelper().queryInventoryAsync(this);
    }
    else{
        //TODO: Messaggio di errore nella creazione dell'IabHelper
        Log.d(TAG, "Errore nel setup dell'IabHelper. Risultato dell'operazione: " + result);
    }

    billingManager.setSetupFinished(true);
}

public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Richiesta dei prodotti acquistabili finita risultato: ");

    if (result.isSuccess()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Successo. Sono stati trovati i seguenti prodotti: ");

        Purchase premiumUpgrade = inventory.getPurchase(billingManager.getPremiumUpgradeSku());

        if (premiumUpgrade != null) {
            String sku = premiumUpgrade.getSku();

            Log.d(TAG, "Rilevato acquisto in app: " + sku);
            alert("E' stato trovato il seguente prodotto in app: " + premiumUpgrade.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Nessun prodotto rilevato");
            alert("Non è stato trovato nessun prodotto in-app. Result: " + result);
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.e(TAG, "Fallito. Inventario non ricevuto.");
    }
    //MainActivity.setWaitScreen(false);

    Log.d(TAG, "Distruggo il billing manager e procedo all'avvio della lista.");

    billingManager.destroy(this);
    start();
}
```

LOG (Ignore the part in italian)

```
05-20 19:51:33.328 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/Billing Manager: Costruzione...
05-20 19:51:33.328 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Starting in-app billing setup.
05-20 19:51:33.358 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Billing service connected.
05-20 19:51:33.358 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
05-20 19:51:33.358 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: In-app billing version 3 supported for cf.portaChiavi
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Subscription re-signup AVAILABLE.
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/Main Activity: Setup dell'IabHelper e del BroadcastReceiver completato con successo.
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/Main Activity: Richiedo la lista dei prodotti disponibili
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Starting async operation: refresh inventory
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Querying owned items, item type: inapp

05-20 19:51:33.368 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Owned items response: 0
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Continuation token: null
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Querying SKU details.
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Querying owned items, item type: subs
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Package name: cf.portaChiavi
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Owned items response: 0
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Continuation token: null
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Querying SKU details.
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
05-20 19:51:33.378 24746-25561/cf.portaChiavi D/IabHelper: Ending async operation: refresh inventory
05-20 19:51:33.388 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
05-20 19:51:33.398 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/Main Activity: Richiesta dei prodotti acquistabili finita risultato: 
05-20 19:51:33.398 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/Main Activity: Successo. Sono stati trovati i seguenti prodotti: 
05-20 19:51:33.398 24746-24746/cf.portaChiavi D/Main Activity: Nessun prodotto rilevato
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the sku name matches in code matches what you have defined in the developer console? Also, are you using a signed image to test this?

Comment: Yes @MobileDeveloper. I test this version of my app with an alpha apk on my device with another account and it doesn't work. It return that there isn't any items to purchase for my app. In fact the problem is not the call of getSku() methods becouse, according to the log (line 17) there is not any items in the inventory ("Nothing to do because there are no SKUs").

Comment: I am referring to the getPremiumUpgradeSku() call.

Answer (score -1):

If you tried to purchase the `android.test.purchased` item before, it can corrupt the inventory. Try clearing the cache of the Google Play application.